# Rails Migrations: tried to change the type of column from string to integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, casting, rails-migrations

I created a table in my rails app with rails generate migrations command. Here is that migration file:

```
class CreateListings < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :listings do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :telephone
      t.string :latitude
      t.string :longitude

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Then I wanted to store the latitude and longitude as integers so
I tried to run:

```
rails generate migration changeColumnType
```

and the contents of that file are:

```
class ChangeColumnType < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    #change latitude columntype from string to integertype
    change_column :listings, :latitude, :integer
    change_column :listings, :longitude, :integer
    #change longitude columntype from string to integer type
  end

  def down  
  end
end
```

I was expecting the column type to change however the rake was aborted and the following error message appeared. I was wondering why this did not go through? Im using postgresql in my app.

```
rake db:migrate
==  ChangeColumnType: migrating ===============================================
-- change_column(:listings, :latitude, :integer)
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::Error: ERROR:  column "latitude" cannot be cast to type integer
: ALTER TABLE "listings" ALTER COLUMN "latitude" TYPE integer

Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

NOTE: The table has no DATA.
Thanks

Comment: Ensure you have no data on it and you could try make a rollback

Comment: If there's no data you can simply remove the columns and re-add them with the correct type. A whole degree of lat/long is pretty big so you might want to think about what type you really want for those columns.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I quote the manual about [`ALTER TABLE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html#id-1.9.3.35.5):

> A `USING` clause must be provided if there is no implicit or assignment
> cast from old to new type.

What you need is:

```
ALTER TABLE listings ALTER longitude TYPE integer USING longitude::int;
ALTER TABLE listings ALTER latitude  TYPE integer USING latitude::int;
```

Or shorter and faster (for big tables) in one command:

```
ALTER TABLE listings
  ALTER longitude TYPE integer USING longitude::int
, ALTER latitude  TYPE integer USING latitude::int;
```

This **works with or without data** as long as all entries are valid as `integer`.
If the column has a `DEFAULT`, you may have to drop that (before the above) and recreate (after the above) for the new type.

Here is a [blog article on how to do this with ActiveRecord](https://webjazz.blogspot.com/2010/03/how-to-alter-columns-in-postgresql.html).
Or go with @mu's advice in the comment. He knows his Ruby. I only know well about the PostgreSQL part.

Comment: For a one-off, the easiest thing to do is wrap the SQL in a `connection.execute('...')` rather that mucking around with monkey patching.

Comment: For solution in rails migration please take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10690289/rails-gmaps4rails-gem-on-postgres

Answer (score 26):

I would include the raw SQL in your migration file like below so that it updates schema.rb.

```
class ChangeColumnType < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    execute 'ALTER TABLE listings ALTER COLUMN latitude TYPE integer USING (latitude::integer)'
    execute 'ALTER TABLE listings ALTER COLUMN longitude TYPE integer USING (longitude::integer)'
  end

  def down
    execute 'ALTER TABLE listings ALTER COLUMN latitude TYPE text USING (latitude::text)'
    execute 'ALTER TABLE listings ALTER COLUMN longitude TYPE text USING (longitude::text)'
  end
end
```

Comment: Note that the down ALTER should be varchar instead of text to match the string type.

Answer (score 24):

I know this a bit ugly, but I prefer to just remove the column and add again with the new type:

```
 def change
     remove_column :mytable, :mycolumn
     add_column :mytable, :mycolumn, :integer, default: 0
 end
```

Comment: I ran a migration change_column :mytable, :mycolumn, :float.  Then ran a couple more migrations, pushed to github, pushed to heroku only to get this error.  I ran a new migration as you suggest above, but the error still persists because of the previous migration.  Now I can't rollback because remove_column is irreversible.  Am I fubar?

Comment: Update to prior comment:  I deleted the prior migration with 'rails destroy migration migration_name' then rake db:migrate and now all is well.

Comment: after hours of trying this helped me to convert boolean to enum

Answer (score 12):

The following is a more `rails way` to approach the problem. For my case I had two columns in my purchases table that I needed to convert from type string to float.

```
def change
    change_column :purchases, :mc_gross, 'float USING CAST(mc_gross AS float)'
    change_column :purchases, :mc_fee, 'float USING CAST(mc_fee AS float)'
end
```

That did the trick for me.

Comment: While it is good to know how to intervene in postgreSQL, one can lose track of such a change.  This rails way leaves a trace for the operation.

Answer (score 2):

1. Do you have existing data in those columns?
2. You should not use int for latitude and longitude. They should be in floating points instead.

Comment: Using an integer or long in (eg) degrees*10^12 of lat/long can be a lot faster and more storage efficient if you know in advance the resolution you need. PITA to work with, though, and prone to conversion error unless all your algorithms can work with it natively in that form. I agree that double or float is safer unless you know you need something different and have good reasons.

Comment: Here's Google Maps' explanation and recommendation: https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax#createtable

Answer (score 0):

latitude and longitude is decimal

```
rails g scaffold client name:string email:string 'latitude:decimal{12,3}' 'longitude:decimal{12,3}' 

class CreateClients < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :clients do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :email
      t.decimal :latitude, precision: 12, scale: 3
      t.decimal :longitude, precision: 12, scale: 3

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```