# Rails Change Column Type Migration for Both MySQL and Postgres

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, migration

I have a rails application which is running on different databases depends on client preferences. I have a "catalog_item_specifications" table which has a column "bec_id". The type of the column is string. Now I want to change the type of the column to integer. When I write:

```
change_column :catalog_item_specifications, :bec_id, :integer
```

It works fine on MySQL but failed on postgres. So according to this post: [Rails - gmaps4rails gem on postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10690289/rails-gmaps4rails-gem-on-postgres)
I changed my migration to the following:

```
connection.execute(%q{
    alter table catalog_item_specifications
    alter column bec_id
    type integer using bec_id::integer
})
```

It now work on Postgres but failed on MySQL. I need a solution (without dropping and re-adding) which will work for both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of those cases where you might be best just checking which database engine is running, and then use the command that works for that engine.

Something like this:

```
if connection.adapter_name.downcase == 'postgresql'
  connection.execute(%q{
    alter table catalog_item_specifications
    alter column bec_id
    type integer using bec_id::integer
  })
else
  change_column :catalog_item_specifications, :bec_id, :integer
end
```

Where `'postgresql'` is the adapter_name (you'll have to check to see what it actually is when you are migrating against Postgres).

Comment: I actually end up with this solution, than saw same answer here. Good to know that I was on right track!