# How to convert postgres column type from string to float

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, database-normalization, floating-point-conversion

I have a rails app with a basic postgres db, but I realized that some of my columns are strings and it'd be best if they were floats. I'm trying to convert columns for latitude and longitude from varchar to floating-point.

I've tried this post [Rails - gmaps4rails gem on postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10690289/rails-gmaps4rails-gem-on-postgres) but I kept getting this error, `ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type double precision: ""`.  I'm willing to try anything else, and I've seen solutions for ways to do it with postgres queries, but I'm uncertain of how to implement them.  It's a straightforward problem; "-73.88537758790638" I want to become -73.88537758790638.  I just can't seem to find a working solution or one that I understand how to implement.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**Empty strings** cannot be converted to a number for obvious reasons.
You have to account for that. Replace all occurrences with `NULL` or `0` or something compatible.

For the number of fractional digits in your example you want the data type **`numeric`**, not float - neither `real` (`float4`) nor `double precision` (`float8`). Those are lossy types and not exact enough. See:

- [Fetch records that are non zero after the decimal point in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15240652/fetch-records-that-are-non-zero-after-the-decimal-point-in-postgresql/15284333#15284333)

Try for yourself:

```
SELECT '-73.88537758790638'::real             AS _float4
      ,'-73.88537758790638'::double precision AS _float8
      ,'-73.88537758790638'::numeric          AS _numeric;
```

Result (up to Postgres 11):

```
_float4  | _float8           | _numeric
---------+-------------------+-------------------
-73.8854 | -73.8853775879064 | -73.88537758790638
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=23e8df3d6e016fee36e02f5c10ea8322)*

Display improved in Postgres 12 (more [`extra_float_digits`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-EXTRA-FLOAT-DIGITS) by default):

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=23e8df3d6e016fee36e02f5c10ea8322)*

[Numeric types in the manual.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html)

#### Solution

Single SQL statement (replacing empty strings with `NULL`):

```
ALTER TABLE tbl
ALTER COLUMN col1 TYPE numeric USING NULLIF(col1, '')::numeric;
```

Comment: How would you do that in psql?

Comment: Awesome, but the only problem is that AR is returning to me the number as a BigDecimal object. Do I have to convert it to a double precision to avoid that?

Comment: @Tsiege: `decimal` and `numeric` are the same in Postgres. `numeric` is the SQL default. You *can* cast to `double precision` but I fail to see why. You'd loose precision.

Comment: I understand, but this is what is returned to me otherwise ```Complaint.first.latitude
 #=> <BigDecimal:7fd9606acb88,'0.4067606251 08629E2',27(27)> ```

Comment: @Tsiege: How to deal with numeric types in AR and Ruby is another question, really. I am no expert with either. Just answered the question at hand.

Comment: @Tsiege There's nothing wrong with using a BigDecimal, it is a Numeric just like Fixnum and Float so it shouldn't make any difference in Ruby-land.

Comment: Gotcha, but I'm going to be doing a lot of mapping, and I don't want  any extra method calls. I checked it out on google maps, and it ignores that last decimal point either way.  I used the recommended PSQL command above but swapped ```numeric``` with ```double precision```.  Thanks, @ErwinBrandstetter for clarifying things.

Answer (score 0):

This is a really simple thing to do in rails using a native ORM approach:

```
change_column :restaurants, :column_name, ‘double precision USING CAST(column_name AS double precision)'
```

Comment: Bit of a postgres n00b here, but when I try this, PG doesn't like it:  syntax error near 'USING'