# Combine SUM and CAST - not working?

Tags: postgresql, casting, sum

PostgreSQL Unicode 9.01 doesn't like:

```
SELECT table1.fielda,
SUM (CAST (table2.fielda AS INT)) AS header.specific
FROM *etc*
```

What is wrong with SUM-CAST?

Error Message:

> Incorrect column expression: 'SUM (CAST
>   (specifics_nfl_3pl_work_order_item.delivery_quantity AS INT))

Query:

```
SELECT specifics_nfl_3pl_work_order.work_order_number,
specifics_nfl_3pl_work_order.goods_issue_date,
specifics_nfl_3pl_work_order.order_status_id,
SUM (CAST (specifics_nfl_3pl_work_order_item.delivery_quantity AS INT)) AS units
FROM public.specifics_nfl_3pl_work_order specifics_nfl_3pl_work_order,
public.specifics_nfl_3pl_work_order_item specifics_nfl_3pl_work_order_item,
public.specifics_nfl_order_status specifics_nfl_order_status
WHERE specifics_nfl_3pl_work_order.order_status_id In (3,17,14) 
AND specifics_nfl_3pl_work_order_item.specifics_nfl_work_order_id=
specifics_nfl_3pl_work_order.id 
AND ((specifics_nfl_3pl_work_order.sold_to_id<>'0000000000') 
AND (specifics_nfl_3pl_work_order.goods_issue_date>={d '2013-08-01'}))
```

It would be really great if you can help.

Comment: What is `header.specific` ?

Comment: Missing: table definition, Postgres version, error message, explanation for query.

Comment: Thanks Erwin:  I have posted the actual code now.  I appreciate your reply.

Comment: BTW: it looks like ORM output to me.

Comment: Ok, I looked-up ORM.  It sounds like MS Query might qualify as ORM..? I began the query in MS Query, but then tried to modify it using Postgre Documentation (yes, I'm very new at this)

Comment: `PostgreSQL Unicode 9.01` is the *ODBC Driver* version; please `select version()` to get the actual PostgreSQL server version. That said, if it's also 9.0.1, **upgrade now**: That version has a known security vulnerability and you're also missing 12 point-releases of fixes. Seriously, *upgrade to 9.0.13*.

Comment: You can get the *table definition* by running `\d table1` in [psql](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/psql/info) or you could use a GUI like [pgAdmin](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/pgadmin/info).

Comment: Also consider fixing your first example. `AS header.specific` is a misleading syntax error. You can't have a dot in an unquoted alias.

Comment: Ok, I went to GUI - it is 9.1.6 version.

Answer (score 2):

If I were you, then I would do these steps:

- give your table short aliases
- format the query
- use proper ANSI joins:
- remove spaces between function name and (

---

```
select
    o.work_order_number,
    o.goods_issue_date,
    o.order_status_id,
    sum(cast(oi.delivery_quantity as int)) as units
from public.specifics_nfl_3pl_work_order as o
    inner join public.specifics_nfl_3pl_work_order_item as oi on
       oi.specifics_nfl_work_order_id = o.id
    -- inner join public.specifics_nfl_order_status os -- seems redundant
where
    o.order_status_id In (3,17,14) and
    o.sold_to_id <> '0000000000' and
    o.goods_issue_date >= {d '2013-08-01'}
```

Actually I really think you need group by clause here:

```
select
    o.work_order_number,
    o.goods_issue_date,
    o.order_status_id,
    sum(cast(oi.delivery_quantity as int)) as units
from public.specifics_nfl_3pl_work_order as o
    inner join public.specifics_nfl_3pl_work_order_item as oi on
       oi.specifics_nfl_work_order_id = o.id
where
    o.order_status_id In (3,17,14) and
    o.sold_to_id <> '0000000000' and
    o.goods_issue_date >= {d '2013-08-01'}
group by
    o.work_order_number,
    o.goods_issue_date,
    o.order_status_id
```

if it still doesn't work - try to comment sum and see is it working?

Comment: +1 on rewriting the query in proper format. Good catch on the missing `GROUP BY`. That's probably the immediate cause of the error. There are more problems ...

Comment: Thanks @ErwinBrandstetter, readability is one of the top of my priorities, that's why I like SQL and Python so much :)

Answer (score 0):

But you have a table2 or only table1?

Try:
    SELECT table1.fielda,
    SUM (CAST (table1.fielda AS INT)) AS "header.specific"
    FROM *etc*

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what [@Roman already cleared up](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18170350/939860), there are more problems here:

```
SELECT o.work_order_number
      ,o.goods_issue_date
      ,o.order_status_id
      ,SUM(CAST(oi.delivery_quantity AS INT)) AS units -- suspicious
FROM   public.specifics_nfl_3pl_work_order o,
JOIN   public.specifics_nfl_3pl_work_order_item oi
                                     ON oi.specifics_nfl_work_order_id = o.id 
CROSS  JOIN public.specifics_nfl_order_status os -- probably wrong
WHERE  o.order_status_id IN (3,17,14)
AND    o.sold_to_id <> '0000000000'              -- suspicious
AND    o.goods_issue_date> = {d '2013-08-01'}    -- nonsense
GROUP  BY 1, 2, 3
```

- `o.goods_issue_date> = {d '2013-08-01'}` is **syntactical nonsense**. Maybe you mean:
  `o.goods_issue_date> = '2013-08-01'`
- You have the table `specifics_nfl_order_status` in your `FROM` list, but without any expression connecting it to the rest. This effectively results in a **[`CROSS JOIN`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM)**, which results in a Cartesian product and is almost certainly wrong in a very expensive way: every row is combined with every row of the rest:
  `CROSS  JOIN public.specifics_nfl_order_status os`
  Either remove the table (since you don't use it) or add a `WHERE` or `ON` clause to connect it to the rest. Note, that it is *not just redundant*, it has a dramatic effect on the result as it is.
- This `WHERE` clause is suspicious:
  `AND    o.sold_to_id <> '0000000000'`
  Seems like you are storing numbers as strings or otherwise confusing the two.
  Also, `CAST (oi.delivery_quantity AS INT)` **should not be needed** to begin with. The column should be of data type `integer` or some other appropriate numeric type to begin with. Be sure to use **proper [data types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype.html)**.
- The default setting of [**`search_path`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067335/how-to-create-table-inside-specific-schema-by-default-in-postgres/9067777#9067777) includes `public`, and you *may* not need to schema-qualify tables. Instead of `public.specifics_nfl_3pl_work_order`, it may suffice to use:
  `specifics_nfl_3pl_work_order`
- `GROUP  BY 1, 2, 3` is using positional parameters, just a notational shortcut for:
  `GROUP BY o.work_order_number, o.goods_issue_date, o.order_status_id`
  [Details in the manual.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-GROUPBY)
- According to comments you are using `MS Query` to create the query. This is not the best of ideas. Produces the kind of inferior code you presented us with. You may want to get rid of that while you are working with PostgreSQL.

Comment: Wow!  Thank you all for "schooling" me.  I will look through all of this now that I'm back at the computer.  You have been generous in helping-out a newbie.  I intend to rely less upon MS Query now and learn how to do it myself.  Thanks for not considering this post a waste of your time.  I will study it all carefully.

Comment: btw, all of the code, including `o.goods_issue_date> = {d '2013-08-01'}` nonsense, was generated by MS Query, except the `SUM(CAST)` - because MS Query doesn't do that.  But when I added that line the query quit working.

Comment: ... Yes, indeed the database frequently stores numbers as text (and I have no control over that) - that's what got me into the problem I am trying to solve - can't add the text _numbers_.  But in the case of `sold_to_id` it is account number - so text is ok.

Comment: **IT WORKED** (two days later).  Now I'm going to try one on my own - no MS Query - for the other element of my report.

Comment: @user2670949: Congrats! If you should need it, here is some advice [how to change the data type for table columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10343383/rails-migrations-tried-to-change-the-type-of-column-from-string-to-integer/10343444#10343444).