# Change column datatype from Text to Integer in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, casting

I am using the following query to change the data type of a column from text to integer but getting error:

```
 alter table a.attend alter column terminal TYPE INTEGER ;
```

> ERROR:  column "terminal" cannot be cast automatically to type integer

Answer (score 86, accepted):

```
create table test(id varchar );
insert into test values('1');
insert into test values('11');
insert into test values('12');

select * from test

 --Result--
 id
 character varying
--------------------------
 1
 11
 12
```

You can see from the above table that I have used the data type – `character varying` for `id`
column. But it was a mistake because I am always giving `integers` as `id`. So using `varchar` here is a bad practice. So let’s try to change the column type to `integer`.

```
ALTER TABLE test ALTER COLUMN id TYPE integer;
```

But it returns:

> ERROR: column “id” cannot be cast automatically to type integer SQL
>   state: 42804 Hint: Specify a USING expression to perform the
>   conversion

That means we can’t simply change the data type because data is already there in the column. Since the data is of type `character varying` Postgres can't expect it as integer though we entered integers only. So now, as Postgres suggested we can use the `USING` expression to cast our data into integers.

```
ALTER TABLE test ALTER COLUMN id  TYPE integer USING (id::integer);
```

It Works.

---

So you should use

```
alter table a.attend alter column terminal TYPE INTEGER  USING (terminal::integer) ;
```

Comment: The `USING` clause is only required if there is no implicit assignment cast defined between source and target type. Details [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10343383/rails-migrations-tried-to-change-the-type-of-column-from-string-to-integer/10343444#10343444) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21045909/generate-series-of-dates-using-date-type-as-input/21051215#21051215).

Comment: This is going to sound silly, but don't forget to replace `id` in `USING (id::integer)`. I accidentally turned one of my columns into a copy of the `id` column. Lucky for me, I was just experimenting so no harm no foul :D