# Can't change the type of a column from date to integer

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, types, ddl

I'm currently trying to use the solution found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26439033/change-column-datatype-from-text-to-integer-in-postgresql), but I don't seem to be able to change the type of the users column from `date` to `integer`.

When I try:

```
ALTER TABLE users ALTER COLUMN password_reset_expires TYPE integer;
```

I get this error:

> ```
> ERROR:  column "password_reset_expires" cannot be cast automatically to type integer
> HINT:  You might need to specify "USING password_reset_expires::integer".
> ```

And when I try:

```
ALTER TABLE users ALTER COLUMN password_reset_expires TYPE integer
USING (password_reset_expires::integer);
```

The error tells me:

> ```
> ERROR:  cannot cast type date to integer
> LINE 1: ...expires TYPE integer USING (password_reset_expires::integer)...
> ```

My table definition:

```
                                            Table "public.users"
         Column         |          Type          | Collation | Nullable |              Default
------------------------+------------------------+-----------+----------+-----------------------------------
 id                     | bigint                 |           | not null | nextval('users_id_seq'::regclass)
 name                   | character varying(20)  |           | not null |
 email                  | character varying(100) |           | not null |
 password               | character varying(500) |           | not null |
 password_changed_at    | date                   |           |          |
 password_reset_token   | character varying(300) |           |          |
 password_reset_expires | date                   |           |          |
Indexes:
    "users_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "tokens" CONSTRAINT "tokens_token_pk_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (fk_users_id) REFERENCES users(id)
```

Here is one of my user objects:

```
{
  id: '59',
  name: 'visitor',
  email: 'visitor',
  password: '$2b$10$0UGgdRUlXFYeQfk5Nv/vXe9khdzyyOqsTiFGyNXLfEDuOFAt0xc1G',
  password_changed_at: null,
  password_reset_token: null,
  password_reset_expires: null
}
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  It is not obvious what value you want for a given date.

Comment: @GordonLinoff just added an example of an user at the end. What I want to store in `password_reset_expires` and `password_changed_at` is a number like this 1594329364292

Comment: Why would you want to do that to begin with? Date values should be stored in `date` columns and date/time values should be stored in `timestamp` or `timestamptz` columns. Don't use the stupid epoch to do that. https://blog.sql-workbench.eu/post/epoch-mania/

Answer (score 2):

Basically, use the SQL-standard function [`EXTRACT()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT). Your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62824293/cant-change-the-type-of-a-column-from-date-to-integer-in-postgresql/62824903#comment111097498_62824293):

> What I want to store in `password_reset_expires` and `password_changed_at` is a number like this 1594329364292

... indicates you want to store the **number of milliseconds since the UNIX epoch 1970-01-01 00:00:00** as integer value. But that's out of range for [type `integer`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html) (signed `int4`), which allows numbers up to *2^31 - 1 = 2147483647*. At the time of writing, already 1594335691272 milliseconds have passed since the epoch.

Either store **seconds** in an `integer` column:

```
ALTER TABLE users ALTER COLUMN password_reset_expires TYPE integer
USING (EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM password_reset_expires)::int);
```

Or store **milliseconds** in a [`bigint`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html) column
(signed `int8`, allows up to *2^63 - 1 = 9223372036854775807*):

```
ALTER TABLE users ALTER COLUMN password_reset_expires TYPE bigint -- !
USING (EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM password_reset_expires)::bigint * 1000);
```

`EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM ...)` returns, according to [the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT):

> For `timestamp with time zone` values, the number of seconds since
> 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC (can be negative); for `date` and `timestamp`
> values, the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 local time;
> for `interval` values, the total number of seconds in the interval

Since the source is `date` in this case, there cannot be fractional seconds and we can just multiply by 1000 to get the number of milliseconds.

Then again, if there cannot be milliseconds, why store the number of milliseconds to begin with?

More importantly, why not keep `date`? If the value actually represents a date, the data type `date` is almost certainly the best option.