# Convert a type to another in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, type-conversion

I have a table of cars in my Postgres database, but a created the price column with varchar.

I want to convert this type to numeric or integer.

[car database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPZnU.png)

Comment: Are you sure about *integer* part? Some of the prices have decimal places.

Comment: What do you mean by "*convert*"?  Are you creating a new column?

Comment: Please your sample data as text, never as image. Ideally, add a fiddle. How many rows are populated? Any NULL values? A column default? Your version of Postgres?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the table definition with [`ALTER TYPE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html#id-1.9.3.35.5), but you'll need a USING clause with your particular conversion. Related:

- [Rails Migrations: tried to change the type of column from string to integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10343383/rails-migrations-tried-to-change-the-type-of-column-from-string-to-integer/10343444#10343444)

If your data sample tells the full story, this should work:

```sql
ALTER TABLE tbl
ALTER COLUMN price TYPE numeric USING right(price, -1)::numeric
```

`right(price, -1)` trims the first character, which is always `$` in your sample. Remaining leading and trailing white space is no problem. Related:

- [Postgres data type cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13676816/postgres-data-type-cast/13676871#13676871)

For anything else, adapt the expression.

The operation triggers a table rewrite, taking an exclusive lock on the table for the duration.

I chose `numeric` to cover fractional digits. See:

- [Which datatype should be used for currency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15726535/which-datatype-should-be-used-for-currency/15729573#15729573)